# How to pass string into Macro iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, macros

I am using **macro for getting localization string.**
Here is my code:

```
#define languagePrefix @"en"
#define localizeStringFormat(key,...) NSLocalizedString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",languagePrefix,key,##__VA_ARGS__],@"")
```

But I am not able to pass string in it. **Can anyone tell me how to pass string into macro ?**

Comment: Who said that macro doesn't allow string as argument ? Can you post the code where you are using the macro

Comment: I am using like this localizeStringFormat(BasicInfo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for this. Please try the below code.

```
#define languagePrefix @"en"

#define localizeKey(key) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",languagePrefix,key]
#define localizeStringFormat(key,...) NSLocalizedString(localizeKey(key),@"")
```

You can print this with:

```
NSLog(@"%@",localizeStringFormat(@"enSignUpBasicProfileTitle"));
```